# Как автоматизировать процесс замены одного куска кода на другой?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня на сайте во многих местах используется указательный курсор

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Проблема в том, что сейчас нужно поменять этот указательный курсор на свой, кастомный

```
cursor: url('../icons/custom_cur.svg');
```

Можно как-то js-ом автоматизировать процесс замены, чтобы везде не менять pointer на url? Т.к этих мест около 500 во всём коде.

Comment: Открываете любую программу, которая позволяет делать замену в файлах. Делаете

Answer (score 2):

```css
.custom-pointer {
  cursor: pointer; /* <- change here */
}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block custom-pointer"></div>
<div class="block custom-pointer"></div>
```